# how pick data in listbox from db?

Tags: .net

i am developing software using VS 2008 and at back end Oracle 10g.

my first question is: can i use LINQ for oracle?
or/and

is there a way without using LINQ can i join more than one source to collect result.
e.g. i have two dataset one is for category named cat_set and 2nd for product named prd_set
now i want to list the product on the basis/specific to selected category in 2nd set.

i made two dataset. one for category which upload data from db in combobox and 2nd in ListBox but only for selected category in the combobox.

thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a dataset1 in which data picked from oracle 10g. table name category_m (cat_1d,cat_name). 2nd product (prd_code,prd_name,cat_id). and there is a combobox in which all category shown when user select one category from combo then listbox should be filled with product info. specific to selected above category. remember there is two dataset one for category and 2nd for product –

Comment: can you please update your original question - you cannot really efficiently show table structure and table contents in a comment - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to connect to Oracle and use LINQ:

- DevArt has [DotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) that supports Oracle, so you can use Linq to query your underlying data
- Mindscape [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/) is an ORM (alternative to Linq-to-SQL or EF) which also supports Oracle as a backend and has full LINQ support

There are other projects out there, but I don't really know much about them (how complete and how stable and reliable they are).

I don't quite understand your second question about joining two datasets to fill a dropdown - can you elaborate a bit? Can you give us an idea what these two datasets look like (what fields they have), and which pieces you'd like to show up in the combobox? Which should be the display field, which should be the value field?